# How can I write this C function so the users can call it without using "free" afterwards?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, free

I am very new to C programming and have a basic question about memory management.

I have written the following code (which works!) to encode some ASCII characters into a certain format I need:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char *hexdigits = "0123456789ABCDEF";

/*
 * Each ASCII byte is encoded as two hexadecimal digits.
 */
char* makeHex (uint8_t* inputBuffer, int inputSize) {
    int i, j;
    char* compositionBuffer = (char*) malloc(inputSize*2 + 1);
    for (i = j = 0; i < inputSize; i++) {
        unsigned char c;
        c = (inputBuffer[i] >> 4) & 0xf;
        compositionBuffer[j++] = hexdigits[c];
        c = inputBuffer[i] & 0xf;
        compositionBuffer[j++] = hexdigits[c];
    }
    return compositionBuffer;
}

int main(void) {
  char a[] = "ABCD";
  uint8_t* inputBuffer = (uint8_t*) a;
  int inputSize = sizeof(inputBuffer);
  int q;
  for (q = 0; q < 10000; q++) {
    char* p = makeHex(inputBuffer, inputSize);
    puts(p); // This outputs "41424344" which is correct.
    free(p); // I am interested in this line
  }
}
```

Now, I'd like to be able to perform this function *without* having to remember to run `free(p)` every time. If I simply remove that line, there is a memory leak.

Please can somebody suggest an alternative way to write this, so the users of the function don't need to concern themselves with memory management?

Comment: The size of `compositionBuffer` appears to be known at compile time. You could define a second array in in `main` beside `a`, then pass in a pointer to the array to `makeHex`. Then it will be free'd automatically when `main` exits. There is no way to avoid needing to `free` when using `malloc` as far as I know. Technically, in this particular case it shouldn't be a big deal because the OS should reclaim resources when the program ends regardless, but it's not a good habit to develop.

Comment: Thanks. In this instance the size is known at compile time but this is just an example usage, in practice the text may be of variable length each time the function is called. This will run on a microcontroller so there's no actual program exit, the real `main` will loop forever and needs to keep tight reigns on how much memory is in use. What *might* be possible is allocating the maximum size that we will *ever* allow at the start of the program, so your answer could well be a pointer in the direction of a usable workaround.

Comment: Oh, then you'll definitely need  dynamic memory allocation unless you have the option of using Variable Lengthed Arrays, and you're stuck with using `free` unless the "massive, this-better-be-enough array is sufficient, and availanle memory allows for it. I think the best you could do is some elaborate macro that `malloc`s/`free`s for you, but that would likely be a mess (although maybe a fun project on its own).

Comment: Write it in c++ or rust if you want dynamically allocated memory to be freed automatically

Comment: OT: regarding; `char* compositionBuffer = (char*) malloc(inputSize*2 + 1);`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code (and is error prone).  Suggest removing that cast.  2) the function: `malloc()` is expecting a `size-t` parameter, not a `int` parameter.  3) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) then call: `perror( "malloc failed" );` This error is not recoverable, so cleanup and call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you might be able to automate the freeing of memory allocated by `malloc()` in certain scenarios, in practice it's entirely typical for a C function that returns a pointer to require the caller to do something to clean up. The clean-up might be a simple call to `free()`, as in your example, or it might be some specific function if it's a data structure that has complex clean-up requirements.

If you define a function that returns a `char *`, any experienced C programmer who reads the code will be alive to the fact that the caller *might* have to free it. I would be careful to document any instance where that *isn't* the case.

In practice, if the function returned a pointer to something that didn't need to be free'd, I'd define the return type as `const`. In such a situation case, it's very probable that the data returned is something the caller shouldn't manipulate, and the compiler should warn if I try to free a `const` pointer.

In short, stop worrying, and learn to love `free()` ;)